# Timer component keeps going when time over

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I rewrote my class component to a functional component but I this I made a mistake somewhere. I can find out what it is. The timer keeps going when the time is up. I think its the useEffect that i use wrong? The class componed worked fine but I need the functional to use redux.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import '../style/App.scss';

function CountdownTimer(){
    const io = require('socket.io-client');
    const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3001/", {
        reconnection: false
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if(running){
            handleStart()
        }
    });
    let timer = null;
    const [time, setTime] = useState(0.1*60);
    const [running, setRunning] = useState(true);


    const handleStart= () =>  {
        if (running){
            timer = setInterval(() => {
                if (time === 0){
                    console.log("no more time");
                    handleStop()
                }else{
                    const newTime = time - 1;
                    setTime(
                        newTime >= 0 ? newTime : handleStop
                    );
                }
            }, 1000);

        }
    }

    const handleStop = () =>  {
        if(timer) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            setRunning(false);
        }
    }

    const format = (time) => {
        const date = new Date(time * 1000);
        let hh = date.getUTCHours();
        let mm = date.getUTCMinutes();
        let ss = date.getSeconds();
        if (hh < 10) {hh = "0"+hh;}
        if (mm < 10) {mm = "0"+mm;}
        if (ss < 10) {ss = "0"+ss;}
        return '00' !== hh ? hh+":"+mm+":"+ss : mm+":"+ss;
    }

    return(
        <div className="icon-value">
            <h1>{format(time)}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
export default CountdownTimer;
```

Comment: Check out this [blog post](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) by [Dan Abramov](https://mobile.twitter.com/dan_abramov) on using `setInteval()` in combination with hooks.

Comment: @alexkucksdorf Thanks ill take a look at this!

Comment: @marijn, made few changes in your code , https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-curran-qmel5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @VivekDoshi Thank I just got it working but ill take a look at your edits and see and learn how you did it. Thanks all